# SQL Server 2014 SP2 upgrade on Alwayson + FCI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering, high-availability

I want to upgrade my SQL Server 2014 to SP2 which is involved in SQL Server FCI and Alwayson. Below is my environment details:

```
    Nodes: SERVER-A, SERVER-B, SERVER-C, SERVER-D
    SQL Server clustered instances : Instance-A, Instance-B, Instance-C
    SQL Server edition and version : SQL Server 2014 EE SP1 on all 3 clustered instances
    Windows server edition and version : Windows server 2012 R2 STD
```

1. SQL Server clustered Instance-A runs on SERVER-A and is installed
   between SERVER-A and SERVER-B.
2. SQL Server clustered Instance-B runs on SERVER-B and is installed
   between SERVER-A and SERVER-B.
3. SQL Server clustered Instance-C runs on SERVER-C and is installed
       between SERVER-C and SERVER-D.
4. SQL Server clustered Instance-A has Alwayson configured for some DBs between Instance-A and Instance-C. Instance-A acts as Primary replica and clustered Instance-C acts as its secondary replica. Alwayson failover mode for DBs is manual.

Please let me know how should I go about patching both my SQL Server clustered instances and any precautions to be taken.

Comment: This either can't be the full setup or we're missing something. If you had an two FCIs in this configuration you wouldn't be allowed to put an AG across them as they would potentially have the same owner nodes - which is checked. Please update the question.

Comment: @SeanGallardy: Thank you for correcting me! I messed up some details and have corrected it now. Please see my update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances
I've used this method several times on 2 and 3 node AlwaysOn Availability Group implementations, and it works very well, and is explained in great detail in the above link.